# How to copy an array of JSON objects in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have an array of objects in JavaScript. e.g. `current_films[0].f_name, current_films[0].f_pattern` etc. I want to copy the array into another similiar to the following:

```
for(var i=0; i<current_films.length; i++)
    {
            if(current_films[i].f_material == Value)
                {
                    temp[i] = current_films[i];
                }
    }
```

However, there seems to be an inexplicable problem when I do this. By inexplicable problem, I mean that the code does not execute and the array is not copied as I desire.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you!

P.S. Could you please mention why the above code would not work? As in, if I put an `alert("Reached here");`, it's not getting executed. Any ideas why its so?

Comment: try javascript for in loop for object

Comment: What is `Value`? Can you give us a sample data that you expect to get?

Comment: Your `temp` array will be sparse -- the indexes will not be sequential from 0, only the indexes from `current_film` that match `Value` will exist. Is that the problem?

Comment: `Value` is just a string. Right now, I am just trying to copy all those objects whose `f_material` attribute matches `Value`

Comment: There is no such thing as a "JSON object"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One problem I see is that you set `temp[i]` to the value which means there would be gaps in the `temp` array.  You could use [`push()`](http://www.javascripture.com/Array#push) to append the value to `temp` so you don't need to manage two sets of indices.

You could also use [`JavaScript's Array.filter()`](http://www.javascripture.com/Array#filter) to do this a little easier.  Filter will return a new array of the values from the original array where your function returns `true`.

```
var temp = current_films.filter(function(film) {
  return (film.f_material === Value);
});
```

Comment: consider cloning if required.

Comment: @nkron I would use === instead of ==

Comment: Yeah, that would be better.  I've made that change.

Comment: Thanks @nkron! This worked! Do you have any idea why the code I wrote was not allowing an `alert("Reached here");` to execute?

Answer (score 0):

> P.S. Could you please mention why the above code would not work? As in, if I put an alert("Reached here");, it's not getting executed. Any ideas why its so?

I'd guess **f_material** is not defined for every element in the array.

If that's the case I'd use

```
if(typeof(current_films[i].f_material)!=='undefined')
{
    if(current_films[i].f_material == Value)
    {
        temp[i] = current_films[i];
    }
}
```

Anyway I'd suggest you to get familiar with the browser's javascript debugger (assumed that code runs in a browser)

Finally note that you're not **copying** the array/object:

temp[i] is a **reference** to current_films[i]

Modifying **current_films** later in the code will result in modifying **temp**

If that's not the behaviour desired Google for "javascript object copy".